# Java Palindrome (Boolean Method) with iterative solution (while loop)

Tags: java, iteration, palindrome

Why doesn't my palindrome program work correctly? It **always** returns `false`, and I can't tell why.

Here is my code:

```
public static boolean isPalindromIterative(String string) {
    int a = 0;
    int b = string.length() - 1;        
    while (b > a) {
        if (a != b) {            
            return false;
        }
        a++;
        b--;        
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing values of a and b which aren't the same when you start comparing and hence you get false from your method.

In your if condition, Change it to be `string.charAt(a) != string.chatAt(b)`

Comment: yep helped me out :) thanks :/ now i feel dumb :D thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

When you say

```
while (b > a) {
    if (a != b) {
```

It's clear that `a` is not equal to `b` (or the loop wouldn't be entered). Going by context, I believe you wanted to compare the characters in the `String`. I would use [`String.toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--) to get a `char[]` and do something like

```
char[] chars = string.toCharArray();
while (b > a) {
    if (chars[a] != chars[b]) {
```

Answer (score 0):

If `b > a` in your code `while (b > a)`, then `a` doesn't equal to `b` in your code `if (a != b)`.

Answer (score 0):

To check given string is palindrome or not in java simply use `StringBuilder` class `reverse()` method and check with given string.

```
    public static boolean isPalindromIterativeStringBuilder(String string) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string);
            sb.reverse(); //Reverse to the given string
            return sb.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(string); //Check whether given string is equal to reverse string or not
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also an iterative method.
I would be happy if I helped someone. ;)

```
public static boolean isPalindromeIterative(String string) {
String polindromCheck = string.toUpperCase();
for (int index = 0; index < polindromCheck.length(); index++) {
  if (polindromCheck.charAt(index) != polindromCheck.charAt(string.length() - 1 - index)) {
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
}
```